# Bash Awk to print number of letters in each word

Tags: bash, awk, io

Hey all so I am writing a bash script that will take a file with a single line such as:

```
Hello this is my test sentence.
```

And count how many letter there are in each word and produce output such as:

```
5 4 2 2 4 4
```

This is what I have written:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN {k=1}
{
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
    stuff[k]=length($i)
    printf("%d ", stuff[k])
    k++
  }
}
END {
  printf("%d ", stuff[k])
  printf("\n")
}'
```

and it gives me the output:

```
5 4 2 2 4 4
```

It is not recognizing how many letters there are in the last word of the sentence. Instead it is using the second to last number again. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your script is rather convoluted, but using it, I get an output such as "5 4 2 2 4 9 0", with the zero appearing because of the END clause.  And at some time you'll have to debate the merits of counting `.` as a letter, but that's a secondary problem.  Unless there was an urgent need for the lengths all on a single line, I'd probably use: `awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print length($i)}'` which gives the output `5 4 2 2 4 9`.

Comment: Anyway to remove the space at the beginning of output without removing spacing between numbers? EDIT: solved problem myself. changed print statement to.. `{printf length($i) " "}`

Comment: Of course: `awk '{pad=""; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/, "", $i); printf("%s%d", pad, length($i)); pad=" ";} print ""}'` which gives you a line of output for each line of input, and for the input string "`Hello, this is my test sentence.`" gives the output `5 4 2 2 4 8` all on one line, spaces between but no spaces before or after.

Answer (score 1):

No need for awk:

```
echo Hello this is my test sentence. | { 
    read -a words
    for ((i=0 ; i<${#words[@]}; i++)) ; do
        words[i]=${#words[i]}
    done
    echo "${words[@]}"
}
```

Comment: That's a little like walking 30 miles to work each day because there's "No need for a car" :-). It also will count the "." at the end of the sentence as part of the word `sentence` when the OP stated he just wants to count letters so it'll report 9 instead of 8 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash only :

```
[ ~]$ str="Hello this is my test sentence"
[ ~]$ for word in $str; do echo -n "${#word} "; done; echo ""
5 4 2 2 4 8
```

Another solution with bash array :

```
[ ~]$ echo $str|(read -a words; for word in "${words[@]}"; do echo -n "${#word} "; done; echo "")
5 4 2 2 4 8
```

Comment: Won't handle the '.' at the end of the posted sample input line correctly and will convert `\t` to a literal tab char which almost certainly isn't desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "word" you mean text separated by spaces, this will literally `count how many letter there are in each word` as requested:

```
$ cat file                                                      
Hello this is my test sentence.
and here is another sentence

$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,"",$i)}1' file
5 4 2 2 4 8
3 4 2 7 8
```

and if you wanted to count all characters, not just letters, it'd be:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=length($i)}1' file               
5 4 2 2 4 9
3 4 2 7 8
```

Comment: +1 for using `$i` on the LHS of the assignment for conciseness. I prefer this solution to mine due to its generality.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo Hello this is my test sentence. | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf " " length($i)}; print "" }'
 5 4 2 2 4 9
```

Or, with the sentence in a file called `sentence`:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf " " length($i)}; print "" }' sentence
 5 4 2 2 4 9
```

If we want to remove the leading space:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%s%s",length($i),(i==NF?"\n":FS)} }' sentence
5 4 2 2 4 9
```

Comment: "sentence" only contains 8 letters, not 9. The OP said he wanted to `count how many letter there are in each word`.